# How to solve the determinant matrix with words using python? there are how solve using the word x in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, cpu-word, determinants

How do I solve the determinant of this matrix using python? 
there are how solve using the word x in python?

```
p = np.array([[x, 1],
              [1, x]])
```

Comment: Try `np.linalg.det(p)`.

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy.linalg.det()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_determinant.htm) function calculates the determinant of the input matrix.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]]) 
print np.linalg.det(a)
```

Comment: Hi, there are how solve using the word x in python?

Comment: If you want to do "symbolic computation" (rearranging symbols rather than using actual numbers) in Python, you'll want the sympy library. Try it: 
x = symbols(['x']) # Turnx into symbolic variable
p = np.array([[x, 1], [1, x]])